# What are the options for day care and baby help for poor single mother?

Tags: newborn, money, single-parent, working-parents, usa

A young woman expects a baby in few months, she is poor and she has no family in the USA. She lives in Boston and it's not an option to move away at this moment (education). Her salary is around 2K/month and all goes for renting 1 small tiny room and food. She has no support from anyone (father of the baby left). It's impossible to find a single room to live with a newborn because nobody wants to be housemates with screaming baby. It's impossible to afford day care for a baby since day cares cost her entire salary. She needs to work all day long and study late nights. So she needs someone to take care of a child at least from 8 am to 6-7 pm.

What are her options to protect and take care of her baby while being a sole money and care provider?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at: https://singlemotherguide.com/financial-help-for-single-mothers-in-massachusetts/

At the income you report, she should qualify for most of those programs, including those that provide childcare support. She should call every one of them, even if she thinks she doesn't qualify. She should also investigate what childcare support is available from her university.

Further, there are other single parents looking to share apartments, don't assume there aren't. She should consider placing an ad on Craigslist about it. She may find a situation where childminding duties can be shared.